# Checklist app, can reuse list

Tags: osx, ios, productivity

I am looking for a checklist app. For example, in preparation for going to the gym, I want to go through my *gym prep* list and check all the items that I need.

It should be very easy to repeat these checklists. Starting a list should be one tap and once I checked all the items the list should be `completed`. When I want to use the list again I want to find it all unchecked.

I dont need a todo list with a thousand features for adding and organizing new tasks, timers, GPS and what not. I do not often modify these lists. I bought an expensive to-do app and now I need to manually uncheck items to simulate the checklist behaviour.

Is there anything that does this? Ideally for iOS and Mac.

Comment: just one little hint: i would look for shopping list apps... they have pretty much the workflow you described.

Answer (score -1):

Things (https://culturedcode.com) is a simple yet extremely powerful task manager for macOS and iOS. It offers automation with the Things ULS scheme (https://culturedcode.com/things/support/articles/2803573/), where you can create lists you need again and again.

Answer (score -1):

I use **Microsoft ToDo** (formally Wunderlist) for this exact purpose. It's available as an app or website. I have a "GYM" list and tick items off one by one. Those items end up down the bottom in the "Completed" section - so you can restore them in preparation for your next workout.

https://todo.microsoft.com/